# importing requests seems to only work in shell

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I've been testing some stuff with requests in python 3.7 shell and it works fine but as soon as I try and automate it by putting it into a file and running it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\simple_http_server\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import http.cookies as cookies
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http.cookies'; 'http' is not a package

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\burp.py", line 6, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .exceptions import (
  File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\exceptions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import (
  File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 203, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\http.py", line 1, in <module>
    import simple_http_server
  File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\simple_http_server\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    import Cookie as cookies
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cookie'
```

Here's my code:

```
import json
import requests

data = requests.post("https://api.rec.net:443/api/players/v4/bulk", data={"Ids[]": "836571"})
jsonload = json.loads(data.text)
print(jsonload[0]["Bio"])
```

[Here's both shells side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmSPw.png)

Comment: Are you sure your running the file under the same python version? Do you have multiple python versions installed?

Comment: yep, same version. The only difference from what I can see is the shell generated from the program has it's path on my desktop and the shell where the import works has it's path set in Python32/Lib/idlelib

Comment: That does sound like a different python version.

Comment: added a screenshot to the post

Comment: Those are two different environments from the looks of it, but both are a 3.7.2 shell. What is the difference between them?

Comment: Wait, holdup, you're starting a shell from the script?!

Comment: No, The shell is just to check that requests works. It works in a separate shell but if I import requests from the program's shell, it gives an error

Comment: How are you running the file? In an IDE? From a command prompt?

Comment: Running the file from IDE and command prompt gives the error. Importing requests from python cmd gives an error. Importing requests from IDLE python shell seems to be the only working method

Comment: Did you try pip install requests in the command prompt? It might not be correctly installed there.

Comment: Requirement already satisfied. Turns out requests can be imported from cmd. It seems that as soon as I open and run the program it becomes unable to import requests

Comment: What did you call the python file?

Comment: I called it test.py

Comment: Aside: you don't need to use the `json` library for the JSON response. `requests` has a built-in function [`json()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) that you can directly use. Your code: `jsonload = data.json()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out the problem. I had a file in the same directory called http which was causing all the problems. Thanks for all the help everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do, `import requests`, is very simple.
Let's back up and create a simple setup for running your script.

Create a brand new conda environment, or pip virtualenv if you prefer.
Use `conda install requests` to get *one* library (plus its transitive deps).
What we're going for is an environment that does *not* have the `six` [compat lib](https://pypi.org/project/six/) present, that is, `import six` fails.
We want it to fail, since that library was causing you grief, as seen in your stack trace.
It renames modules you don't want renamed, including `http`.

Now, from shell or IDE, use the new environment to run your script.

Finally, since `test` is a standard module that ships with python, you're probably better off renaming your code to something else, perhaps `test1.py`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment. The size of the error has significantly decreased, however, the program now asks that I install simple_http_server. Should I install it?

Comment: Sounds like you're getting into more complex code than you showed in your question. I am not familiar with https://pypi.org/project/simple-http-server/, myself, as I usually go the Flask route. Sure, go for it, what could it hurt? If it doesn't work out you can always start a new environment and strip the code down so you have something working, and then keep adding one more item until it breaks, then you know which item is responsible.

Comment: Strange, I'm only using requests but it seems requests wants to use simple_http_server